# Can I rent a small plane (Cessna) in Europe?

Tags: europe, rental, aircraft

A friend of mine has a commercial pilot license, he was able to rent small planes in the US and fly it from one state to another. He told me a lot of fun stories and I am kinda excited to do the same but in Europe with him as the pilot. His license is issued from the US and is FAA approved. Now we are planning to travel from one country to another, we are thinking of Italy as a start point but this can change if it is not possible from Italy.

**Will we be able to rent a small plane (Cessna) in Europe and fly there just like my friend did in the US?**

Comment: I'm pretty certain that it's possible. You (or anyone else reading this) might be able to find more comprehensive information about it on [aviation.se], where most of the people who regularly answer questions are actually pilots. [Here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2845) is a question I asked specifically referring to what's required for a U.S. pilot in the Philippines. [Here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/183) is one that discusses European pilots flying in the U.S. (opposite of your situation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to several pilot's forums it may be possible to do:

- [US pilots discussing plane rental in Germany](http://www.pilotsofamerica.com/forum/showthread.php?t=35485)
- [Similar discussion in a different forum again about Germany](http://www.pprune.org/private-flying/356181-n-reg-aircraft-rental-europe.html)
- [Rental Agency in Prague](http://www.aeroprague.com/aircraft_rental.htm)

The best I can figure you will need an [FAA license, current medical, etc](http://www.pilotsofamerica.com/forum/showpost.php?p=580568&postcount=6).